# Javascript - Unterminated string constant

Tags: javascript

When I run the website, it says "Error: Unterminated String Constant". The code that it says is the problem is:

```
var icsdate = currentDate.getFullYear() + currentDate.getMonth() + currentDate.getDate() + "T" + currentDate.getHours() + currentDate.getMinutes() + currentDate.getSeconds() + "Z";
```

The full script is:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

       var currentDate = new Date();
       var icsdate = currentDate.getFullYear() + currentDate.getMonth() + currentDate.getDate() + "T" + currentDate.getHours() + currentDate.getMinutes() + currentDate.getSeconds() + "Z";
       var inonehour = currentDate.getHours() + 1;
       var icsenddate = currentDate.getFullYear() + currentDate.getMonth() + currentDate.getDate() + "T" + inonehour + currentDate.getMinutes() + currentDate.getSeconds() + "Z";
       var location = "USA"

       var msgData1 = icsdate;
       var msgData2 = icsenddate;
       var msgData3 = location;

       var icsMSG = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//Our Company//NONSGML v1.0//EN\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nUID:me@google.com\nDTSTAMP:20120315T170000Z\nATTENDEE;CN=My Self ;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:me@gmail.com\nORGANIZER;CN=Me:MAILTO::me@gmail.com\nDTSTART:" + msgData1 +"\nDTEND:" + msgData2 +"\nLOCATION:" + msgData3 + "\nSUMMARY:Our Meeting Office\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR";


       $('.button').click(function () {
           window.open("data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG));
       });
   </script>
```

Comment: Considering that the code you've provided in the question gives no such error,  I don't know how you'd expect anyone to be able to help.

Comment: What comes before this in your code?  The line you've posted is not the cause of that error so we need to see more code around this in order to have any chance at helping you.

Comment: The full code is above. Will this help?

Answer (score 0):

#### `location` is a readonly property in JavaScript

The exact line of code you've singled out itself doesn't give the *"Error: Unterminated String Constant"* error message, **however** specifying `var location = "USA"` in the global scope will attempt to override the readonly `window.location` object and will attempt to redirect your browser to the page `/USA`, and I imagine that is possibly what's affecting your code here.

You should rename `location` to something else.

---

For example, running the following code snippet in Chrome...

```js
var location = "USA";
```

...will give the following error message:

> [image: Error Message]

In other browsers it'll possibly throw different errors, such as the one you're getting on whichever browser it is you're using.

Comment: I changed the name of the variable to "eventlocation", but now when I run it, it shows the button, but nothing happens. Is there anything else that could be the problem?